# how to create directed graph in codename one

Tags: codenameone

[image: directed Graph]

I want to create directed graph that will have capability of dragging and 
reconnecting nodes etc just like in the diagram. Instead of circles there will be some icons. I really want to add this capability in my application. How do I proceed for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two articles on drawing graphics in Codename One. You can use that to draw pretty much anything:

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-graphics

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-graphics-part-2-drawing-an-analog-clock

You can also use Components to represent the individual nodes and then use a `GlassPane` to draw the lines between them. You would be able to position the elements in the graph by using a custom layout manager (there is a tutorial on that in the developer guide).

Comment: So i will be able to develop application like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modelmakertools.simplemindfree&hl=en)

Comment: Sure but its not a simple task in any platform to build a graph of this type.

Comment: I have to prepare a mock to show to the client. If I will be able to develop smallest unit ( just two nodes connected ), i'm done. Through I have two other question related to the pricing and licence, shall I mention here.

Comment: I am not familiar with your programming experience so I can't tell you how hard something would be. SVG isn't supported well natively by Android or iOS (only in the webkit implementation which is pretty slow). You can ask questions by filing new questions or here: http://codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html